# after redirected to URL in android browser app is not getting open

Tags: android, redirect, deep-linking, android-deep-link, android-app-links

I have login with 3rd party system which works fine. but after being redirected to our server android browser not opens my app which already configures with redirected URL in manifest.xml.

steps

1. user opens the app and clicks on login with 3rd party.
2. app opens the URL of 3rd party in the chrome browser.
3. user being authenticated and 3rd party service redirected to our server.
4. the redirected URL has one more redirection. (it is last actually) and that previous URL I am observing in my android app. men's android system should open my app as soon as the browser has redirected the URL.
5. but it opens the URL in the browser.

**Note** asset link file was also uploaded.
The app links assistant's test link feature is working perfectly means I provide it my URL and it opens the app.

**ideal Scenario**

APP -> browser (after authentication) -> APP (open or bring in foreground)

manifest sample

```
`<activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:exported="true"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data
                        android:host="example.com"
                        android:pathPrefix="/dossier" />
    
                    <data android:scheme="http"/>
                    <data android:scheme="https"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>`
```

Comment: As you haven't shown your manifest code i assume over here that you have added ```queries``` tag and ```intent-filter``` . for more detail of queries tag you can refer this link
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/queries-element

Comment: @jayeshgurudayalani I  updated with the intent-filter but I don't have a query tag. can you guide me?

Comment: you can add these lines above ```<application>``` and under ```<manifest>```


```
<queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*" />
        </intent>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Comment: I did try this but still no success. browser not opening app

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution for this?

Comment: @el07 yes I am able to solve it but it was a long long journey

Comment: do you mind to share how you solve it please?

Comment: My issue with the Android app was not able to access .well-known server because our server was deployed within the local network. it was accessible through VPN . but for Google verification was not possible.

Comment: but also you gusy have to add a button on website or some code with triggers the redirection to a link which will open the app.

Comment: if you guys need help we can get a call and I can help you.

Comment: I want to do it without the button , my use case is that user gets a link in email, if he clicks on it, it will trigger verification and the then it will redirect to my app Universal link. That's where it is getting stuck. It should open the app on redirect but it open the website where .well-known is hosted.